# Java - Rename duplicate file instead of selected file

Tags: java, html, file, file-io

Background - I've a script TableToCSV that converts a .html table file to .csv file, however it requires that we input a  xyz.html to it via console. But the files selected aren't always with a .html extension, they usually have .xls - although the content inside is .html. So I want my program to make a copy of the selected file, then make a copy (or a temporary file) which can be stored in C:\Dtemp\ and then finally rename it from xyz.xls to xyz.html

Currently it renames the selected file to xyz.html.

Here is my code

```
final JFileChooser  fileDialog = new JFileChooser();
    JButton btnInputFile = new JButton("Input File");
    btnInputFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            //other code
            int returnVal = fileDialog.showOpenDialog(rootPane);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
               java.io.File file = fileDialog.getSelectedFile();

               String name = file.getName();
               name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));
               name += ".html";
               File newFile = new File(file.getParentFile(), name);
               if (file.renameTo(newFile)) {
                   try {
                    TableToCSV tableToCSV = new TableToCSV(newFile, ',', '\"', '#', CSV.UTF8Charset );
                    System.out.println("action");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            //other code
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code explicitly renames your input file to the new name (`file.renameTo(newFile)` ). Iv you want to copy the file, why don't you copy "file" to "newFile" instead.  You have to do the copy yourself (reading in `file` and writing `newFile`)

(You might want to check the input file first line to make sure it really is an html file (by looking at the content).